# Does QGraphicsItem::mapFromItem() account for transformations?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I want to place an item (foreground) above another item (background) at a certain coordinate (x, y) of the background. The background is
transformed and foreground and background are in no parent-child relation.

I thus would do:

```
foreground->setPos(foreground->mapToParent(
        foreground->mapFromScene(background->mapToScene(x, y))))
```

First determine where on the scene the background coordinate will be after transformation of the background, then map this coord from the scene to the foreground item's parent coordinate system for the `setPos()` call.

However this seems to be equivalent (at least in my case) to:

```
foreground->setPos(foreground->mapToParent(
        foreground->mapFromItem(background, (x, y))))
```

Does `mapFromItem(item)` account for any transformation applied to `item`? Or is the equivalency just an artifact of my overall situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you define that foreground is the parent of background, Qt will translate background automatically if the position of foreground changes.

```
background->setParent(foreground);
background->setPos(20,20); // cooridinate system origin is pos() of foreground.
foreground->setPos(10,10); // background moves also
```